# How to add a trash icon to the Ubuntu dock in GNOME?

Tags: gnome-shell, trash, ubuntu-dock

How do I add Trash to my GNOME shell favorites (and thus to Ubuntu dock)?

**Ubuntu 16.04 Unity - Trash Bin**

[image]